# Would+do or did?

Tags: word-choice

kindly help me which one is correct.

**Situation**:two guys are talking to each other, suddenly, the first guy has asked the second guy a favor.

First guy:can you talk to that girl and get her number?
Second guy: I think, I would just screw up if I **did/do** that.

Which one is the correct verb tense here 'did' or 'do'? Thx very much.

Comment: This question is better suited to [ell.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your given situation fits the [first conditional](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-and-wishes/conditionals-if), since the imagined situation of him screwing up is quite likely (at least in his opinion).

So, it is:

> I think, I would just screw up, if I do that.

Comment: No, in remote conditionals, it should be the modal preterite "did". Present tense "do" would only work with the open conditional "will", i.e. "I will just screw up if I do that".

Comment: @Geshode: A misleading answer.  This doesn't explain at all why you wouldn't use the "second conditional".  I can obviously say "If I took poison, I would die", even if the dying would be highly likely.  It is the taking of the poison that is being specified as unlikely.  Similarly then, if I said "If I did that, I would screw up", it's the doing it that's being represented as unlikely, not the screwing up.  Further, if you used the first conditional, why wouldn't you use "will"?

Answer (score 4):

[1] *I think I **would** just screw up [if I **did** that]*.

[2] *I think I **will** just screw up [if I **do** that].*

In the apodosis of a remote conditional like [1] a modal preterite is required, thus "did" is correct.

But in an open conditional like [2], a present tense verb is required, so "do" would be correct here.

Note: a remote conditional is one where the condition is not fulfilled or is a relatively remote possibility whereas an open conditional is one that is neutral as to whether the condition is or will be met.

Comment: You beat me to it :)